# Non HTTPS URL adds extra WWW infront

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

If you visit [Non HTTPS version](http://www.macmetro.com) it will not redirect to the HTTPS version. Instead it will look like https://www.www.mywebsite.com and will not work. This is the code in my htaccess file.

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove www. from this line:

```
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or you can do it like this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But I want to keep the www infront of my URL's

Comment: I want this redirect to be cacheable so shouldn't we leave the 301 in there?

Comment: Did not work for me, I am adding my website link please check.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks Ryan for your fast responses and support.